# How to add listeners for properties in an auto-binding template in Polymer?

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm writing a webapp with Polymer and I'm using an auto-binding template and a property for paging:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <iron-pages selected="{{page}}" attr-for-selected="id">
    <section id="login">
       ...
    </section>
    <section id="main">
       ...
    </section>
  </iron-pages>
</template>
```

But how can I implement a listener function that's fired when `page` changes? In custom elements, I'd use a declared property:

```
Polymer({

  ...

  properties: {
    page: {
      type: String,
      notify: true
    }
  },

  pageChanged: function() {
    // My listener function
  }
});
```

So I tried setting `properties` and `pageChanged` to the template element:

```
var template = document.querySelector('template');
template.properties = { ... };
template.pageChanged = function() { ... };
```

But the `properties` property is already reserved.

Do you have an idea how to do that? Thanks in advance,

Felix

Comment: ever solved this? Been pulling my hair out for hours ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [property observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#change-callbacks):

```
Polymer({

  properties: {
    page: {
      type: String,
      notify: true
      observer: 'pageChanged'
    }
  },

  pageChanged: function(newPage,oldPage) {
    // My listener function
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and `observe:'functionName'` in `page` property which actually changes and in that 
`functionName:function(){
    fire('custom-event');
}`
That is what you are trying to achieve I think.